# T-SQL Delete command basing on table variable

Tags: t-sql, delete-row

I need to delete some rows from table where indexes are equal indexes in table variable

```
  declare @m_table as table
  (
     number NUMERIC(18,0)
  )
...
inserting some rows into @m_table
...
DELETE ct FROM [dbo].[customer_task] ct
          inner join project_customer pc on pc.id_customer = @m_table.number
          inner join customer_user cu on cu.id_project_customer = pc.id
WHERE ct.id_csr_user = cu.id AND ct.id_status = 1;
```

but this code generates an error: **Must declare the scalar variable "@m_table"** How to solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that SQL is expecting you to treat `@m_table` like a standard table, rather than a scalar (int, bit, etc.) variable. Perhaps something like this will work?

```
DELETE ct FROM [dbo].[customer_task] ct
WHERE ct.id_csr_user IN (
    SELECT cu.id FROM customer_user cu
    INNER JOIN project_customer pc ON pc.id = cu.id_project_customer
    WHERE pc.id_customer IN (SELECT number FROM @m_table.number)
) AND ct.id_status = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a '`GO`' (a batch separator) in those '...'

Variable declarations do not span batches.